# how to Display Google Drive Pdf Url in pdfView And Download and print the file t

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, url, wkwebview

hii we have a problem we got a link(Url) of pdf from google Drive
url like This:-"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xYjCqV4LBljBMvn6OsFyK8U6-RK3aGaB/view"
how we can convert this into pdf format.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways to include your file in a PDF

- 1. Just embed a link to the online location, not ideal from a security aspect.
- 2. Embed the media file to be extracted and viewed by another user, but requires them bypassing their security.
- 3. Include the graphics as simple images. (Audio would need to be attached if needed)

You asked how to **print** thus option 3 is the one needed to output a selection of frames as seen here (note the moving pencils on the left)

[image]

There are many tools to do that but the simplest I found was https://document.online-convert.com/convert-to-pdf which produced 2 images per page using 300 Tweens = 150 pages and the first 10 pages are dark fade in intro so can be discarded using a PDF arranger.